# Rails : Storing and retrieving values from multiple select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, multiple-select

I'm wondering what is the best way to store values from a multiple select in the database?

I have a model "People" and I need to store people's preferences which can be multiple values

Should I store their preferences as an array on the same table or create another table with the following structure?

People_Preferences
 - Person_id
 - Preference_id (Storing just one preference_id)

I need to be able to filter by people's preferences.

Which of these approaches is the best or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is a join table "people_preferences" and a habtm relationship to `preferences` from the Person model and another habtm from Preference to Person. That would be my recommendation without hesitation.

But it really depends on a range of factors though. Postgres has support for array types which means no join is needed and an intarray type which can be used to hold foreign keys but referential integrity is harder to achieve when array values reference rows in other tables. If you're using mysql then this is not really an option.